# R - Replace sequence values by its maximum in a column

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

I am with a small problem and hope someone can help me.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(foo = 1:20, bar = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,1,2,3,4))
```

and what to have a result like this:

```
df_result <-  data.frame(foo = 1:20, bar = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,3,3,3,0,0,0,4,4,4,4))
```

How do I do this without using a while loop?

Comment: Have a look at `?rle`.

Comment: @markus A sidenote: your solution is about 10 times faster on larger vectors (e.g. `bar = unlist(sample(lapply(1:10, function(x) sequence(x) - 1), 1e6, replace = TRUE))`. Of course we assume _consecutive_ integer sequences, as shown by OP.

Answer (score 4):

Using `ave` in base R :

```
with(df, as.integer(bar > 0) * (ave(bar, cumsum(bar == 0), FUN = max)))
#[1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 3 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 4 4
```

where `cumsum(bar == 0)` is used to create groups, `ave` is used to calculate `max` in each group and `as.integer(bar > 0)` is to keep value which are 0 as 0.